# How do I serialize telnet like communication on a bidirectional socket connection?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, vb6, telnet

I have implemented TCP/IP communication between a VB and VC++ programs running on the same machine. On the VC++ side I spawn a thread which listens for connections. On the VB side I use the Winsock API to connect to the C++ server. Everything seems to work fine, especially when I manually debug and step through the communication. The protocol is text based, commands terminate on '\n' and may or may not have an answer.

And here is the problem. I'm trying to implement commands which are sent to the server, this requires some processing and the server sends them back to the client. Under simple conditions this works fine, but under heavy load or different machine configurations sometimes the communication gets interrupted.

The client may be sending a command but the server may be sending the answer of a previous command. The VB client somehow gets a fragmented answer (say, instead of a "DATA RECEIVED" it gets "EIVED") which breaks the state machine I've implemented to track the connection.

So yeah, client and server are talking at the same time and this is making a problem. How do I serialize or queue this communication? I understand this would be similar to the problem of network packet collision on ethernet.

Comment: TCP already is serialized - you have a bug in your code.

Comment: More often than not, the bug is in your code. Not the compiler, operating system, or standard template library.

Comment: Yes, if I had not made a bug in my code I wouldn't be asking here for help on an issue I just barely understand. Any suggestions on what can I do to find out where this bug is? Server side? Client side? Is there any way to make sure at least one of the endpoints is doing the stuff right? Maybe a proxy to log/monitor the communication? What tools are there to debug this other than printfs?

Comment: I'd retag this w/o multithreading, telnet, or sockets and add TCP to focus it better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than packet collision, my guess would be that you're reading more than you expect from the socket. Could it be that your last read from the socket looks something like

```
OTHER STUFF\nDATA REC
```

and on the next read you get "EIVED"?

Comment: It may be. The VB is really basic so it only shows the last received message on the GUI. I'll have to log everything to a file and see if the problem is that two answers get queued and delivered in the same socket read. It looks from other answers that TCP is serialized, so it seems the only possible explanation. Is there a TCP equivalent of fflush() which could help me here?

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol.  Imagine reading a file that another process is appending to the end of.  You can only read from where you currently are forward, and only what has gotten committed to disk so far.  There are no "messages" except what your two programs have defined between themselves, so you need to deblock the stream into messages based on some mutual convention (EOR character, length prefix, etc.).  Each call on .GetData after DataArrival only guarantees you one byte of data but could well return 1, 3, or 17 and a half of your "messages."

Comment: Looking at the code and after reading your answers and the guide at http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/wiki/CommonPitfalls I can see now the problem is in the VB client which doesn't expect truncated message nor preserves data after \n when receiving.